Where's the implementation for react-pro-sidebar demo?
I want a beautiful sidebar UI like the one shown in their screenshot here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar
Their demo also shows its usage. However, just using it like this creates a very ugly sidebar. I thought it would look good by default.
<Sidebar>
  <Menu>
    <SubMenu label="Charts">
      <MenuItem> Pie charts </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem> Line charts </MenuItem>
    </SubMenu>
    <MenuItem> Documentation </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem> Calendar </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</Sidebar>;

Where do I get the code that replicates the sidebar shown in their screenshot?

https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar/blob/master/storybook/Playground.tsx

@Odri what's the point of this react component if i still need to do all that work?

no pain no gain
